# Intergrating Social Media into DFP

Tags: jquery, google-dfp

Right now in DFP, I have one line item with 4 different creatives in it which is being fed to 4 different ad units. So basically, I have 4 different ad spots in which 4 ads are being rotated within.  Everything works great.  When you refresh the page the 4 ads appear in different spots and the same two ads are never being displayed twice.  Everything is working great.

But now, I would like to incorporate social media links for every ad. So every ad would have social media links to the corresponding ad and would also rotate with the ad. So say I have 4 ads, and one of the ads is a water bottle ad... I would like to post images / links to their social media (via DFP) and whenever you hit refresh and the water bottle ad moves to a different spot, the social media for the water bottle ad should stick with the ad at all times. So no matter which ad spot the water bottle ad is in, its social media will always be with it.

Here is a website that does exactly what I'm talking about: http://www.vurbmoto.com *(Their advertisements are the bigger images that say "advertisement")*

Notice how each ad has their corresponding social media under it.  When you hit refresh, you will see new ads with the correct social media links for each ad.  The idea of the social media sticking with the ad is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Again, I would like to create social media links / images to always stick with an ad on a refresh / ad rotation.  So, what would be a **strategy** or **method** for doing this in DFP? At this point I am unsure on how to go about this.  Any help would truly, truly, truly be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your ad a third party creative instead of just an image and you can do this.

You could either have the third party creative contain the html to make the social links or you could have some javascript in it that calls out to the links on the parent frame outside of the ad to change the links.